# Add html plugin into wordpress

Tags: html, html5

I purchased an HTML5 Video & Youtube background plugin,

I want to use it with WordPress.

http://codecanyon.net/item/html5-video-youtube-background/1555660

Any Suggestions? Maybe create a template, page,etc..?

Comment: You are asking how to install a WordPress plugin?

Comment: No. The code is not a WordPress plugin. [user2538967](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/36457/user2538967) wants to know how to add the code (which we cannot see) so that it works in WordPress. Why the word "plugin" is in the title is a mystery.

Comment: Sorry, yes, it's not a plugin. It's only an html code. I found a way to do this using iframe, so I create iframe in the targeted page then refer to this code as a source. Any other suggestions?